# Debug Gradle application with instrumented files

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gradle, build, gradle-eclipse

I have Eclipse Neon 4.6.2 and Gradle 4.3 installed locally. My goal is to build and debug a desktop gradle application written in Java.

In command line, to execute the application I have to run `gradle clean build --no-daemon` to generate instrumented class files. After that, I successfully execute the application.

I've tried doing the same in Eclipse because I need to run it with the debugger, so I've installed the Gradle plugin for Eclipse and launched  `clean build` task with `--no-daemon` in program arguments section, but I´m getting this error:

[image: Unknown build argument error]

I have no idea why isn't being recognized `--no-daemon` option which is one of the arguments of gradle build task.

After doing that, I would have to debug it as normal Java application?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the connection between `--no-daemon` and instrumented class files

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run Gradle inside IDE without using daemon.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:tools_and_ides

> The Gradle Tooling API (see Chapter 14, Embedding Gradle using the Tooling API), that is used by IDEs and other tools to integrate with Gradle, **always use the Gradle Daemon to execute builds**. If you are executing Gradle builds from within you're IDE you are using the Gradle Daemon and do not need to enable it for your environment.

Comment: So, cannot debug the application with the instrumented class files? At least a way to build it from console and debug those generated class files from eclipse

Comment: Why do you need to run it without Gradle daemon?